# Object Variable not Set error with autofilters

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating the looping macro to fill missing dates between records (macro is still in progress, so do not pay attention to "loop" part). Unfortunately I am stopped by error in line with autofilters - sorting `Range("A:A")` - Object Variable or With block variable not set - runtime error 91.

Do I need to declare variables also for sorting ranges?

```vb
Sub Usage_report()    
    'OFF
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With
    
    Dim last_row As Long
    Dim latest_date As Variant
    Dim newest_date As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim days_between As Integer
    Dim All_range As Range
    Dim Range As Range
    Dim Range_firstlog As Range
    Dim Range_logYTD As Range
    
    last_row = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Usage report (logins)").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'converting A column to numbers
    Set All_range = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Usage report (logins)").Range("A2:A" & last_row)
    All_range.Select
    With Selection
        .NumberFormat = "0"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    
    'sorting table by ID and date of logging (descending)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Usage report (logins)").ShowAllData
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Usage report (logins)").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
            Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Usage report (logins)").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
            Add2 Key:=Range("A:A"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending _
            , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Usage report (logins)").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
            Add2 Key:=Range("M:M"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending _
            , DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Usage report (logins)").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
          
    'finding the dates - newest and oldest
    latest_date = Format(WorksheetFunction.Min(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Usage report (logins)").Range("M1:M" & last_row)), "mm/dd/yyyy")
    newest_date = Format(WorksheetFunction.Max(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Usage report (logins)").Range("M1:M" & last_row)), "mm/dd/yyyy")
    
    'loop
    For i = last_row To 2 Step -1
        If (ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Usage report (logins)").Range("H" & i).Value < latest_date) And (Not IsEmpty(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Usage report (logins)").Range("M" & i).Value)) Then
            days_between = DateDiff("d", ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Usage report (logins)").Range("M" & i).Value, newest_date)
            For j = 1 To days_between
                Set Range = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Usage report (logins)").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 13))
                Range.Select
                Selection.Copy
                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                Set Range_firstlog = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Usage report (logins)").Range("M" & i)
                Set Range_logYTD = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Usage report (logins)").Range("N" & i)
                Range_firstlog.Offset(j, 0).Value = Range_firstlog.Value + 1
                Range_logYTD.Offset(j, 0).Value = ""
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    
    'ON
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim Range As Range` don't do this.  Do not declare a variable the same name as an object.  It just confuses the readability of the code.  Not your problem just an observance.

Comment: the issue is that you do not specify the parent sheet to the key ranges: `Key:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Usage report (logins)").Range("A:A")`